# Why does this list keep returning NullPointerException in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So basically what this code is supposed to do is Spellcheck one certain word taken as input from an `EditText` field and display the suggestions in the `TextFields`.

`getAll()` is the function that calls all the other operations that need to be performed.

At the end after all functions have been executed `Public member variable "list"` contains all the suggestions.

The last function `sort()` adds all of the suggestions in the `List` `list`. And in the `onClick()` we are trying to print them to `textfield`. But

```
t2.setText(list.get(1).toString());
```

returns `NullPointerException` Error.

The spellcheck code works completely fine when run independently on eclipse.

Here's the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.daipayan.myapplication, PID: 2667
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.daipayan.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

And the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static char keyboard[][] = {{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
                {'0','Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','0'}, //mapping the keyboard to a multidimensional array
                {'0','0','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','0'},
                {'0','0','0','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M','0','0'},
                {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}};


public static String possibleArray[];
public static ArrayList<String> comb;
public static ArrayList<String> filtered;
public static Set<String> dictionary;
public static HashMap<String , Integer> distances;
public static List list;
public static String incorrect_word;


EditText input;
TextView t1,t2,t3;
Button bt1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String inputText = input.getText().toString();

            String words[] = inputText.split("\\s");

            String lastWord = words[words.length-1];

            incorrect_word = "HELLP";
            try {
                getAll();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
            t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
            t1.setText(""+list.get(0));
            t2.setText(list.get(1).toString());
            t3.setText(list.get(2).toString());
        }
    });


}

public static void getAll() throws IOException {
    loadDictionary();
    Log.d("getall","called");
    //System.out.println(checkWord(incorrect_word));

    //
    //fetching the location of characters on the keyboard
    //
    int index[][] = new int[incorrect_word.length()][2];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < incorrect_word.length() ; i++){
        int xy[] = locate(incorrect_word.charAt(i));
        index[i][0]=xy[0];
        index[i][1]=xy[1];
    }

    //print(index, incorrect_word.length(), 2);

    //
    //Fetching all the possible words with the
    //
    ArrayList<String> possible = characters(incorrect_word, index);
    {
        possibleArray = possible.toArray(new String[0]);
        comb = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs("",0);
    }

    filtered = new ArrayList<String>();

    filterCombinations(); //filter out the words that aren't in the dictionary

    Levenshtein(incorrect_word);//Calculate distances between words and the incorrect word

    printHash();//Print the hash map consisting of the words and their respective distances

    sort();
}

public static int[] locate(char a){
    int i=1,j=0;
    for( ; i < 4 ; i++  ){
        for( j=1 ; j < 11; j++ ){
            if(keyboard[i][j]==a)
                return new int[] {i,j};
        }
    }
    return new int[] {i,j};
}

public static ArrayList<String> characters(String incorrect_word, int index[][]){
    ArrayList<String> possible = new ArrayList<String>();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < incorrect_word.length() ; i++){
        String character=""+incorrect_word.charAt(i);
        int x=index[i][0] , y=index[i][1];


        String a = (keyboard[x-1][y] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x-1][y]: "0");//Upper Right
        a = (keyboard[x-1][y-1] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x-1][y-1]: "0");//Upper Left
        a = (keyboard[x][y-1] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x][y-1]: "0");//left
        a = (keyboard[x][y+1] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x][y+1]: "0");//right
        a = (keyboard[x+1][y] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x+1][y]: "0");//Lower Left
        a = (keyboard[x+1][y+1] != '0' ? character+=keyboard[x+1][y+1]: "0");//Lower Right



        possible.add(character);
    }
    return possible;


}

public static void dfs(String x,int i) {
    if(i == possibleArray.length) {   // there is no more string that can be generated
        if(checkWord(x))
            comb.add(x); // save the found string
        return;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<possibleArray[i].length();j++)  // for each character in the current string
        dfs(x+possibleArray[i].charAt(j),i+1); // take the current character and move to the next string
}


public static void loadDictionary() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader dictReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
    dictionary = new HashSet<>();
    while (dictReader.ready())
    {
        String dictInput = dictReader.readLine() ;
        String [] dict = dictInput.split("\\s");

        for(int i = 0; i < dict.length;i++)
        {
            // key and value are identical
            dictionary.add(dict[i]);
        }
    }
    dictReader.close();
}

public static Boolean checkWord(String str){
    String toCheck = str.toLowerCase();
    if(dictionary.contains(toCheck)){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public static void filterCombinations(){        for(String x:comb)
        if ( checkWord(x) )
            filtered.add(x);

}
public static void printHash(){
    Iterator iterator = distances.keySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next().toString();
        String value = distances.get(key).toString();

        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
}
public static void Levenshtein(String incorrect_word){
    distances = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String x:filtered)
        distances.put(x,distance(incorrect_word , x ));

}
public static int distance(String a, String b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    // i == 0
    int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
        costs[j] = j;
    for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
        // j == 0; nw = lev(i - 1, j)
        costs[0] = i;
        int nw = i - 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
            int cj = Math.min(1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]), a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1);
            nw = costs[j];
            costs[j] = cj;
        }
    }
    return costs[b.length()];
}

public static void sort(){

    list=new ArrayList(distances.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2){
            return ((Comparable)((Entry)(obj1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Entry)(obj2)).getValue());
        }
    });
    if(list.size() > 3)
        list.subList(4, list.size()).clear();
    Log.e("list","the values " + list.get(0) + list.get(1)+list.get(2));
}

}
```

Comment: add your error log

Comment: Do you know what `static` means? Why do you think you need it?

Comment: How many items in your List ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan the List contains two strings.

Comment: yes need more information. If you get null pointer exception then it will give you line which one have.

Comment: I bet if you removed static variables (which are a remnant of your Eclipse code), then created a [mcve] and **debug** your app, then youd see why it's null

Comment: @daipayan if two, then how you get third by this t3.setText(list.get(2).toString());

Comment: @cricket_007 Shall try that.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes that is a fault, but the error points to the first setText() statement.

Comment: @daipayan  first setText() ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes at t1.setText(list.get(1).toString());

Comment: Take a log of list.get(1), what it print. It's not IndexOutOfBounds Exception, may be no element present at index one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

According to you List having two element and you're getting third element so it throw NullPointer Exception at `t3.setText(list.get(2).toString());`